# Python MySQL-Connector Inserting Long Text Strings

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Python script running on Windows VPS (shared hosting, remote MySQL connection, limited resources). Inserting text into a MySQL database on Linux. The MySQL data type is "text". When the text is less than 3,000 characters it works fine. When its more than 3,000 characters it times out. Here is the code:

```
import mysql.connector

try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="", user="", password="", database="", connection_timeout=15)
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

sql = "INSERT INTO tableName (experience) VALUES (%s)"

val = ('THREE THOUSAND CHARACTERS OF TEXT') # WORKS FINE

val = ('FOUR THOUSAND CHARACTERS OF TEXT') # TIMEOUT ERRORS

try:
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()
    print("record inserted")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
  
mycursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

Here are the errors:

```
2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at system error: 10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed...
```

And when I remove the timeout parameter from connect:

```
2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at system error: 10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected...
```

The only solution that I can think of is to somehow buffer or upload the text in chunks, but I don't think that can be done with a single record. Help sincerely appreciated.

Comment: post  a create table and increase the wait_timeout

Comment: Please explain. The table already exists. Increasing connection_timeout does not help. What is wait_timeout? Is that a setting in MySQL? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't read the comment completely

the connection timeout is only the time it wait till a connection is established

The wait_timeout is the time the process wait till a query is finished.

So increase the `wait_timeout`

```
 cursor.execute('SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=28800')
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but mycursor = mydb.cursor('SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=30000') doesn't seem to help. Still generating  system error: 10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Comment: that is really a slow connection increase both parameters further, connectione timeout as also the wait